# Alfresco Share Dashlet(UserDashlet and SiteDashlet)

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to create one dashlet which is user-dashlet as well as site dashlet.Alfresco user can add it in both the dashboard, user dashboard as well as site dashborad.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I know in dashlet descriptor's family tag, there are 2 types of values which we can specify, which is user-dashlet and site-dashlet.In this tag can we specify some thing else to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 values which can be specified in family tag of dashlet in Descriptor file.

1.`<family>site-dashlet</family>` - Dashlet will be visible on site dashboard only.

2.`<family>user-dashlet</family>` - Dashlet will be visible in user dashboard only.

3.`<family>dashlet</family>` - It will be visible in both the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep just "dashlet" it should be visible both places